# Single Sign On Solution for this Scenario

Tags: oauth, openid, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to set up a very simple SSO between two cooperating websites A and B. The scenario is as follows:

Suppose that I've visited website A and have been authenticated there with a normal username/password combo. I receive some type of token which identifies my session. I then navigate to website B and automatically want to be logged in. Ideally, I want my session preferences from A to be carried over to B.

I wonder:

1. Is there a standard for the token format?
2. Is there a standard for storing the token in the web session? (Cookie or otherwise)
3. Is there a standard for sending the token to website B? (Parameter names, URLs, Methods?)
4. Is there a standard for website A to contact website B in order to validate that the token is valid, assuming that B trusts A? It would be great if I could receive some metadata related to the user and session in this step as well (username, email, preferences set in session)

I've briefly looked into OAuth 1&2, OpenID, SAML and Mozilla Persona. They all seem to cover similar scenarios, but I can't quite make out if they would support this scenario and in to what extent. Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are these websites ASP.NET?

To do SSO, you need some sort of STS like ADFS v2.0.

If the sites are ASP.NET, then ADFS and WIF will provide the solution you need.

The two standards for Federation / SSO are SAML and WS-Federation.

SAML 1.0 token format is the one most widely used for the token.

There's a good description of all this here : [A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control (2nd Edition)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately they are not .NET, I cannot assume any specific stack. I know that B, which we will control, most likely will be Java.

Comment: The principles remain the same. For Java, the STS could be something like OpenAM.